# How do you use `dotnet ef ...` tooling in a netcoreapp?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm using the 2.0.0-preview version of .net core, and I've created a netcoreapp2.0 app to play with the entity framework core.

The .csproj file is:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\HelloEF.Core\HelloEF.Core.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-preview2-final" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

After calling `dotnet restore` the tooling appears to be installed correctly, as I can successfully use the `dotnet ef` command:

```
$ dotnet ef dbcontext
Usage: dotnet ef dbcontext [options] [command]
...
```

...but attempting to create a migration fails:

```
$ dotnet ef migrations add InitialLoad
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentRootPath
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Utilities.Check.NotEmpty(String value, String parameterName)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations..ctor(IOperationReporter reporter, Assembly assembly, Assembly startupAssembly, String environment, String projectDir, String contentRootPath, String rootNamespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<.ctor>b__4()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.LazyRef`1.get_Value()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: contentRootPath
```

I know this is a preview release, and this may be a bug, but I feel like I might actually be doing something wrong here, rather than it just being broken.

Shouldn't the `ContentRootPath` be detected as the path that `dotnet...` is invoked from?

Do I need to do some other kind of setup to make this work?

All the tutorials around this seem to just assume that if you're using EF core, you're using ASP.NET core too; but I'm not, I'm just creating a command line utility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is misleading. You are just mixing incompatible package versions. Either use `2.0.0-*` for all packages or use `1.1.x-*` for all:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.0.0-*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.0.0-*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Design" Version="2.0.0-*" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.0.0-*" />    
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-*" />
<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet" Version="2.0.0-*" />
```